# How do I incorporate parseInt into this code?

Tags: javascript, html, calculator, parseint

I've got almost no experience with Javascript and I need make a "calculator" type website.
This is the part of the code that is suppose to calculate, but it only adds values together instead of calculating them.

I was told parseInt will fix this, but due to my inexperience I can't find how to do so through Google.

Any help is appreciated and explenations are welcome. Thanks!

```js
    function izracunaj() {
      const st1 = document.getElementById("prvoStevilo").value;
      //določim konstantno ki bo pridobila informacije iz polja kjer smo določili id
      const st2 = document.getElementById("drugoStevilo").value;
      const operacija = document.getElementById("operacija").value;

      let rezultat;

      switch (operacija) {
        //v oklepaje vpišemo operacija, saj to preverjamo
        case '+':
        rezultat = st1+st2;
        break;
        //podatki se skranijo v rezultat
        case '-':
        rezultat = st1-st2;
        break;
        case '*':
        rezultat = st1*st2;
        break;
        case '/':
        rezultat = st1/st2;
        break;
      }
      document.getElementById("rezultat").value = rezultat;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <title>Kalkulator</title>
    <script src="javascript.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>Kalkulator</h2>
    <form>
      Prvo število: <br>
      <input type="text" id="prvoStevilo"> <br>
      Drugo število: <br>
      <input type="text" id="drugoStevilo"> <br>
      Operacija: <br>
      <input type="text" id="operacija"> <br>
      Rezultat: <br>
      <input type="text" id="rezultat" disabled="true"> <br>
      <br><br>
      <input type="button" value="Izračunaj" onclick="izracunaj()">
    </form>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: "I can't find how to do so through Google." The first Google result for `parseInt` is [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt).

Answer (score 2):

When you use `.value` then it will give you the value of type `string`. All you have to do is either use `parseInt` or use `+` to convert it into `number` type

```
parseInt(document.getElementById("prvoStevilo").value, 10);
```

or

```
+document.getElementById("prvoStevilo").value;
```

or

```
Number(document.getElementById("prvoStevilo").value);
```

```js
function izracunaj() {
  const st1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("prvoStevilo").value);   // change
  //določim konstantno ki bo pridobila informacije iz polja kjer smo določili id
  const st2 = +document.getElementById("drugoStevilo").value; // change
  const operacija = document.getElementById("operacija").value;

  let rezultat;

  switch (operacija) {
    //v oklepaje vpišemo operacija, saj to preverjamo
    case '+':
      rezultat = st1 + st2;
      break;
      //podatki se skranijo v rezultat
    case '-':
      rezultat = st1 - st2;
      break;
    case '*':
      rezultat = st1 * st2;
      break;
    case '/':
      rezultat = st1 / st2;
      break;
  }
  document.getElementById("rezultat").value = rezultat;
}
```

```html
<h1>Kalkulator</h2>
  <form>
    Prvo število: <br>
    <input type="text" id="prvoStevilo"> <br> Drugo število: <br>
    <input type="text" id="drugoStevilo"> <br> Operacija: <br>
    <input type="text" id="operacija"> <br> Rezultat: <br>
    <input type="text" id="rezultat" disabled="true"> <br>
    <br><br>
    <input type="button" value="Izračunaj" onclick="izracunaj()">
  </form>
```

Comment: You **must** provide the base when calling parseInt

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteMartin yeah, you're right

Answer (score 0):

You could also let javascript evaluate the equation for you using Function.  I multiply the first two arguments by 1 to force them to either NaN or numeric values, and limit the operator to the four values in the regex in order to sanitize the inputs, then combine the arguments into a string with a template literal.

```js
function izracunaj() {
      
  const st1 = document.getElementById("prvoStevilo").value*1;
  const st2 = document.getElementById("drugoStevilo").value*1;
  const operacija = document.getElementById("operacija").value;
      
  if(!/[+-/*]/.test(operacija)) { return; }
      
  let formula = `return ${st1}${operacija}${st2}`;
  let rezultat = new Function(formula);
      
  document.getElementById("rezultat").value = rezultat();
      
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <title>Kalkulator</title>
    <script src="javascript.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>Kalkulator</h2>
    <form>
      Prvo število: <br>
      <input type="text" id="prvoStevilo"> <br>
      Drugo število: <br>
      <input type="text" id="drugoStevilo"> <br>
      Operacija: <br>
      <input type="text" id="operacija"> <br>
      Rezultat: <br>
      <input type="text" id="rezultat" disabled="true"> <br>
      <br><br>
      <input type="button" value="Izračunaj" onclick="izracunaj()">
    </form>
  </body>

</html>
```